# Create a multilingual site

Tags: php, session

I start today in creating a multi-language system for my site.
To do so I created my two language files then created my switch that here below:

[link](http://viper-7.com/BFk6vN)

To call the file I created simple links

```
<p><a href="index.php?lang=en">English</a><a href="index.php?lang=fr">Français</a></p>
```

When I'm on the home page and I click on "English" translation that do well but if I click on another link to my site I automatically revert to French when I should remain in English!

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you use a session to store the chosen language?

Comment: Yes, you need to use session or cookie for selected language. Means, save "en" or "fr" as "lang" variable either in session or in cookie.

Comment: Can you explain me how?

Comment: @tatane you should have a minimal understanding of what you are asking, if you do not know what cookies or session is, do not ask here, find out.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you always read the GET variable for language and if it's missing, you switch back to the default one (French), which makes storing it inside a session variable - useless.

You should either add `?lang=XX` in all the links and remove the $_SESSION, or you should make the following changes in order to use the session variable:

```
}else { 
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'fr';
include('french.php');  
$langage=$_SESSION['lang'];
}
```

to:

```
}else { 
    if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
        if($_SESSION['lang'] == 'fr'){
            include('french.php');
        }else{
            include('english.php');
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['lang'] = 'fr';
        include('french.php');  
        $langage=$_SESSION['lang'];
    }
}
```

That way, if no language alteration is requested, your script will check if it has a stored language variable, before switching to the default one.

Ideally you should use case instead of IFs if you have more than 2 languages.

```
}else { 
    switch($_SESSION['lang']){
        case 'en':
            include('english.php');
            break;
        case 'es':
            include('spanish.php');
            break;
        //insert other language cases here
        default:
            include('french.php');
            break;
    }
}
```

My advice is, the third option. Many sites have a separate directories for each of languages and look like this: `www.domainname.ext/` for the default language and `www.domainname.ext/xx/` for the other languages, where xx is the abbreviation of the language (en for English and etc.)